# AutoMapper CS File Extremely Slow in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, automapper

I have a solution with 7 or 8 projects, none of which contain anything particularly exciting and all perform as well as you would expect (and indeed as well as other projects I have used on my current machine).

However, whenever I open either one of the AutoMapper MappingConfiguration files, Visual Studio grinds to halt, moving the cursor one space takes minutes at a time and trying to write code results in lots of swearing - lots and lots and lots of swearing.

It seems to only be this `MappingConfig.cs` file. It is isn't even that large - maybe 30 mappings (`cfg.CreateMap<Bar,Foo>();`) and in total 350 lines of code.

**Has anyone experienced slowing of Visual Studio whilst using AutoMapper?**

AutoMapper is 4.2 I believe and I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

Comment: I have the same issue, it's present using AutoMapper 5.x and ReSharper 2016.3 EAP8 as well. Has anyone reported it at ReSharper's side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same thing and reported an issue to the Github repo.

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2217

They saw this as a VS issue but I got a nice answer for `AutoMapper 5.0 <`. Use `AutoMapper Profile Instances` so that you can split the configuration to many separate files. This gives some real performance gains instead of having everything in one file.

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#profile-instances

Answer (score 2):

I have simmilar problem in my solution.
By using [ADK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/dn913721.aspx) i found reason in my case.
Resharper get all cpu perfomance.
Point by point i exclude some features from it, and in result find decision.

Turn Off Resharper IntelliSense, allow work Visual Studio native IntelliSense.

**Resharper menu -> Option -> Environment -> IntelliSense -> General**

Set radio to Visual Studio.

After work with Autommaper CS file, i turn it back.

---

No idea what the matter of this, but i`m guess it Automapper new reflection engine, after update Automapper from 3.1.1 version i got this problem.

But now my CPU on 3-5% level.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks!

Comment: Visual Studio after update 3 problem come back. Remark this answer as correct. I`m looking for another way.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same experience when I start editing the Automapper config cs file. My config file is even smaller (~170 lines of code). Visual Studio starts taking up more than 50% CPU and everything slows down.
I'm using VS2015 (Professional) and, in addition, have resharper 10 installed.
Automapper version is 4.2.1.

Comment: I've not managed to find any fix for it; will be interested to see if anyone else does.

Comment: I am not sure this suites as an answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem since 4.2 I upgraded to 5.1 still same issue seems to be with intellisense or maybe Reshapper?

Anytime you try to do a ForMember like below and the CPU goes up to 50%+ to the point where it takes 30 seconds to type 1 character, I usually have to shutdown visual studio and reopen its making AutoMapper unusable. Or I have to load the file in text editor Mode, but then I lose all the nice intellisense.

Example Code:

> Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
>               {    cfg.CreateMap()
>                     .ForMember(dest => dest.OrderNumber,
>                        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => $"{src.OrderReferenceNumber}"))
>
> };

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue (Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, AutoMapper 4.2.1, Resharper 2016.1.2).

After installing the cumulative servicing update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 ([KB3165756](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=816878)), and upgrading to Resharper 2016.2, the issue is less severe, but it still exists.